# Как уменьшить число классов без использования декораторов?

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Внизу дан пример. Он сделан на декораторах. А чем это лучше такой вот реализации:

Сделать класс **ElementStyle**, от которого сделать наследование в виде множества разных стилей: **ElementStrikedStyle**, **ElementHighlightedStyle**, **ElementInvertedStyle**.

У класса **Element** сделать свойство **styles** как массив элементов типа **ElementStyle**. В него можно вкладывать любое количество в любой комбинации разные стили.

В итоге мы добились такого же результата (те же 4 класса, если не считать родительский), но зато не нужно тратить время на изучение декораторов.

Вот пример на декораторах (взят отсюда http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/patterns-oop-structural-decorator):

> Пример уменьшения числа классов
>
> Предположим, необходимо разработать класс Element, реализующий элемент
>   блок-схемы. Есть четыре стиля его отображения, которые надо
>   комбинировать: по-умолчанию, инвертированный (inverted), зачеркнутый
>   (striked), выделенный (highlighted). Кроме того, необходимо в
>   дальнейшем легко добавлять новые стили и их комбинации.
>
> При использовании наследования получим 8 классов: от Element,
>   ElementInverted, ElementStriked, ElementHighlighted,
>   ElementInvertedStriked и до ElementInvertedStrikedHighlighted.
>   Добавление еще одного стиля, например рамки (ElementBorder), увеличит
>   число классов до 16. Назвать это удобным, простым и надежным решением
>   навряд ли можно.
>
> Использование шаблона Декоратор ограничит число создаваемых классов до
>   4: основной Element и 3 Декоратора (ElementInvert, ElementStrike,
>   ElementHighlight). В дальнейшем возможно их вкладывать один в другой
>   для достижения нужного результата. Кроме того, такой подход более
>   гибкий в работе. Например, можно сначала инвертировать, а потом
>   подсветить или наоборот. Да и поддерживать такой код проще.

Вот и вопрос. Зачем нужны декораторы, если ту же задачу можно решить более простым и понятным способом на ООП?

И плюс решение более гибкое. Декораторы не имеют возможности наследоваться. А тут мы можем спокойно сделать потомка, например класса **ElementHighlightedStyle** (например **ElementColorHighlightedStyle**).

Comment: "если ту же задачу можно решить более простым и понятным способом на ООП"- а применение шаблона Декоратор, это, значит не ООП?

Comment: @Sublihim не знаю. В те времена (лет 20 назад) когда я изучал ООП не было никаких декораторов. Может сейчас декораты часть ООП, а может и нет. Это надо выяснить. Я давно уже не читал ничего нового про ООП. Я лишь знаю что декоратор это шаблон проектирования. Но шаблоны не являются частью ООП. Потому что шаблон можно и в функциональном программировании использовать.

Comment: Стоп. ООП - это всего лишь парадигма программирования. Декораторы не могут входить или не входить в ООП. Сам шаблон Декоратор использует ООП. Вы вправе использовать Декоратор или использовать свой подход в виде агрегирования св-ва style. Это уже дело архитектуры. Ну и, стоить заметить, что *Design Patterns* от GoF существуют с 1994 года, т.е. более 20 лет

Comment: @Sublihim Спасибо за комментарий! А по существу вопроса, Вы можете что-то сказать?

Answer (score 1):

> У класса Element сделать свойство styles как массив элементов типа
>   ElementStyle. В него можно вкладывать любое количество в любой
>   комбинации разные стили.

Т.е. я правильно понял, что у вас будет всего два класса: `Element` и `ElementStyle`? А где в таком случае будут размещаться разные реализации стилей? Внутри одного `ElementStyle`? Если так, то чем новый `if` или `case` блок в таком случае будут отличаться от нового класса?

Речь идет не о том, какое количество классов (сущностей) получится, а о том, как можно легко расширять код. В данном примере: как избавиться от комбинаторного роста классов (сущностей) при расширении требований, и получить один класс (сущность) на одно требование. В этом смысле ваш вариант равнозначен декоратору: при добавлении нового требования в обоих случаях нужно будет добавить одну сущность, будь то класс или `if`/`case`.

Право на жизнь имеют оба варианта. Как обычно, все зависит от сценария. Но количество классов как таковое не должно быть целью. Целью должна быть читаемость и легкость внесения изменений.

Могу привести два довода, в которых декоратор удобнее.

В сценариях, где применяется декоратор, часто важен *порядок*. Например, как было сказано в цитате, элемент сначала инвертируется, а затем подсвечивается. Декоратор позволяет определять этот порядок понятным и недвусмысленным образом:

```
var element = new Element();
var invertedElement = new ElementInvert(element);
var highlightedElement = new ElementHighlight(invertedElement);
// используем highlightedElement
```

В случае же с коллекцией стилей попробуйте, не заглядывая в реализацию, отгадать, в каком порядке они применяются? От первого к последнему? От последнего к первому? А может сортируются каким-то образом?

```
var element = new Element()
{
    Styles =
    {
        new StyleNormal(),
        new StyleInvert(),
        new StyleHighlight()
    }
};
```

Кроме того, объект-декоратор пользуется контрактом декорируемого типа и ничего не знает о его реализации. По описанию исходного примера можно предположить, что логика рисования находится в `Element` и его декораторах. При использовании стилей получается, что либо `Element` должен иметь в своем контракте некоторый метод "рисования", либо логика рисования будет вынесена в сами стили. Это не всегда может быть возможно или удобно.

Comment: Порядок применения стилей в JavaScript гарантирует массив (new Array()). В описании класса Array четко сказано, что элементы перебираются в цикле с гарантированным порядком. Так что в этом плане что декоратор, что без него - порядок применения стилей будет гарантирован.

Comment: А вы написали "В случае же с коллекцией стилей...". Что неверно. Я в своем вопросе четко написал следующее: "...сделать свойство styles как **массив** элементов...". Зачем перевирать мои слова???

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob речь о том, что, не заглядывая в реализацию `Element`, нельзя понять, в каком порядке будут перебираться элементы. Гарантии языка тут ни при чем.

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob под коллекцией я подразумевал набор элементов, по которому можно итерироваться, и не важно, массив это, список или что-то еще. Почему неважно? См. предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: Но по условиям задачи порядок важен. Значит надо массив использовать. А вы взяли и подменили его на объект и представили это как преимущество Декоратора.

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob я повторю свой вопрос: как, глядя на массив, можно узнать, в каком порядке делается его обход? Что мешает классу `Element` производить его обход в обратном или случайном порядке?